# How to get output of fixed pattern in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I had a column called `TRAN_TYPE` in my table and it has data as shown below.

```
TRAN_TYPE
----------
success
failed
123456-001
654321-001
098765-002
time out
```

My requirement is to get the column data which contains continuous 6 digits followed by - and 3 digits.

As per above data my output will be

```
123456-001
654321-001
098765-002
```

Please suggest query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
where regexp_like(tran_type, '^\d{6}-\d{3}$');
```

The `\d` represents a digit, `{6}` and `{3}` are how many times the previous pattern have to be repeated, and they must be separated by a dash. The `^` and `$` are start and end anchors so there can't be anything before or after the digits. [Read more about regular expression support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm).

Demo with your sample data in a CTE:

```
with your_table (tran_type) as (
            select 'success' from dual
  union all select 'failed' from dual
  union all select '123456-001' from dual
  union all select '654321-001' from dual
  union all select '098765-002' from dual
  union all select 'time out' from dual
)
select tran_type
from your_table
where regexp_like(tran_type, '^\d{6}-\d{3}$');

TRAN_TYPE 
----------
123456-001
654321-001
098765-002
```

Or try this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11429/1)